# memory_limit issue php script

Tags: php, config, memory-limit

How exactly does ini_set() work?
I have the  following code .

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');
```

Which throws this

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 31457280 bytes exhausted

However

```
ini_set("memory_limit","30M");
```

works just fine.
How is that possible?
The second value is lower than the first.

Comment: restart your server.

Comment: Does your server have `4GIG` of memory to allocate to each PHP script that runs with this setting in it?

Comment: try using the value in MB (4096M). And i agry with @RiggsFolly. Does server have free memory?

Comment: Do you have suhosin patch installed

Comment: Is this your server or a hosted server?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file lying around somewhere saying php_value memory_limit xyz?

Comment: use phpinfo(); and look what memory limit is used

Comment: Restarting doesnt help, my server is run on my local machine using xampp.I have 4GB of RAM.How can I check if I have enough memory ?phpinfo shows 128MB

Answer (score 0):

HI Try following Code in your php ini_set function

```
  ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```